# android set 2 different font size in a button

Tags: android, html

i want to set 2 different size in a multiline button.

what i do now is using below method but i have no control over the size and does not know how it looks like on different screen size.

```
  final Button btnreset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resetQ);
    btnreset.setText(Html.fromHtml("<big>Click Here</big><br/><small>To Queue</small>"));
```

some of them say instead of using big or small. use html tag. html tag works fine on the color attribute but not size attribute.

```
  final Button btnreset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resetQ);
    btnreset.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font size='9'>Click Here</font><br/><font size='2'>To Queue</font>"));
```

below is my xml coding

```
<Button
                   android:id="@+id/resetQ"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_marginTop="50dp"                     
                   android:text="New Queue"
                       android:textSize="@dimen/lblsize"    
                     android:layout_weight="1" />
```

**Edited**

so now my code becomes

```
  Spannable spannable = new SpannableString("Click Here To Queue");
    spannable.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.5f), 0, 10,Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
   btnreset.setText(spannable);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like this :

```
Spannable spannable = new SpannableString("Click here\nto queue");
spannable.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), 0, 10,Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
spannable.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2f), 11, 20,Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
btnreset.setText(spannable);
```

This sets "Click here" to Bold. Then "to queue" to double size font on the next line.

Comment: how do i move "To Queue" to second line and set the font size as well? currently only start index and end index of first 10 is able to change. how about the rest of the words?

Comment: use `\n` for new line. Use `RelativeSizeSpan` to change size. See updated answer.

Comment: ar. thanks. i didnt know i can declare it again. thanks so much.

Comment: RelativeSizeSpan(2f), 11, 19...
Nineteen.

Answer (score 2):

For Android 5.0 (Lollipop) "or newer" 
add setTransformationMethod(null) to your button (see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26958909/why-is-my-button-text-coerced-to-all-caps-on-lollipop)).

```
Spannable span = new SpannableString(text + "\n" +  underText);
span.setSpan(new AbsoluteSizeSpan(12, true), text.length()+1, text.length()+1+underText.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

Button button = new Button(ctx);
button.setTextSize(16);
button.setText(span);
button.setTransformationMethod(null);
```

Comment: Note that setTransformationMethod(null) also allows directives like <font size="30"> to work