# Android 5.0 (Lollipop) widget button's text are in ALL CAPS

Tags: android, android-widget, android-5.0-lollipop

I have a simple homescreen widget with a few buttons on it. My problem is that when the widgets are running on Lollipop the button's text are all capitalized, any previous Android version doesn't have this problem. The buttons in the layout.xml are very ordinary buttons: no styling or special sauce, just a width height and text size. The interesting thing is that any TextViews I place into the widget aren't affected by this in Lollipop, ie. it appears that only Button objects have this issue.

My AppWidgetProvider is pretty simple too: just sets the sets the text and a PendingIntent for each button.

It sounds like a global styling problem, but I can't find anything in my application's resources that would cause this. Does anyone have any input to this problem? Thanks!

Comment: If you use AppCompat then the system will wrap the all cap style to your buttons

Answer (score 8):

You have 2 options :

1.Use `android:textAllCaps="false"` in your layout-v21 (or anywhere)

2. Programmatically change the transformation method of the button. mButton.setTransformationMethod(null);

Comment: Specifying `android:textAllCaps="false"` on each button worked for me! Though I don't know why it is needed for Lollipop...

Comment: this is a working solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27893840/lollipop-capitalizes-buttons-text-in-my-app/39143743#39143743

Comment: This is the same answer, in fact, the other question should be closed as duplicate of the same as this question.

Comment: Here's a good way of doing it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26958909/why-is-my-button-text-forced-to-all-caps-on-lollipop/43711891#43711891