# Xamarin Android Add button text all caps - How to apply style across the application?

Tags: android, xamarin, android-styles

I am new to mobile development, I am developing a simple app using Xamarin studio and added few buttons on my page. I noticed that all button texts are appeared in CAPITAL LETTERS when i run it in emulator (Android 5.0.1 - API 21).

I already followed [Why is my Button text forced to ALL CAPS on Lollipop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26958909/why-is-my-button-text-coerced-to-all-caps-on-lollipop) and tried to add `<item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>` in my style.xml but it doesn't make any difference.

Also checked [Why is my Button text forced to ALL CAPS on Lollipop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26958909/why-is-my-button-text-coerced-to-all-caps-on-lollipop)  and [Android 5.0 (Lollipop) widget button's text are in ALL CAPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27091353/android-5-0-lollipop-widget-buttons-text-are-in-all-caps).

If I add `android:textAllCaps = "false"` to my all buttons (in my axml files) then it will work but I want to know the generalized style for all buttons across the application (in multiple forms/activities even)

Can anyone please suggest a way to use some style across the application?

Thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can try adding the following in your Resources/values folder as styles.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<resources>
  <!-- Inherit from the light Material Theme -->
  <style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <!-- Customizations go here -->
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Then in your MainActivity.cs, apply this custom theme

```
[Activity(Label = "MyActivity", Theme = "@style/MyCustomTheme")]
```

Comment: Same issue was facing.... solved with your trick... Thank you so much :)