# android:textAllCaps="false" not working for TabLayout design Support

Tags: android, androiddesignsupport, android-tablayout

I have set `android:textAllCaps="false"` in my `android.support.design.widget.TabLayout` thought it is showing the Tab Title in All caps only.

How can I remove all caps?

Comment: I believe you have to define that in a specific style which inherits the base style for a TabLayout.

Comment: @Vannen can please show me some code which solve this issue?

Comment: please use editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.AllCaps()});

Answer (score 224, accepted):

**UPDATE FOR DESIGN LIBRARY 23.2.0+**

The original answer doesn't work with design library 23.2.0 or later. Thanks for @fahmad6 pointed out in comment, in case someone missed that comment, I'll put it here. You need to set both `textAllCaps` and `android:textAllCaps` to `false` to disable all capitalize setting.

```
<style name="MyCustomTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
      <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
      <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

By default, tabs are created by TabLayout sets the textAllCaps property to be true, you have to define a style making this flag false.

```
<style name="MyCustomTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
      <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/MyCustomTextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="MyCustomTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
      <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Your answer look correct but i don't know why, it not worked for me

Comment: @Moinkhan I can't say anything without knowing what you have taken in layout and what code you have written! Look into the code and see if any mistake!

Comment: I am just applying  theme `MyCustomTabLayout` in TabLayout using `app:theme` . I don't think it's wrong...

Comment: @Moinkhan It is working. Use this way  style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"

Comment: The important part here is that the answer is using `textAllCaps` whereas the question is using `android:textAllCaps`.

Comment: This solution stop working with appCompat 23.2.0.

It's wotking with: `android:textAllCaps`

Comment: Interestingly, for reasons I can not explain, I had to explicitly add _both_ `android:textAllCaps` and `textAllCaps` and set them to false for my text to show up as desired (i.e. "Local" instead of "LOCAL"). Trying either alone did not do the trick.

Comment: `<item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>` has no impact on me. I only need `<item name="textAllCaps">false</item>`. Support lib 26.1.0.

Comment: It worked for me. You need to add tabTextAppearance attribute in your tab layout and reference it to MyCustomTextAppearance style. That's it!

Comment: Thanks, this works when you want to set `android:textSize` and `android:textAllCaps` (not an updated answer, but old one).

Comment: Update : It should be used as         `app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyCustomTextAppearance"` then it will work

Comment: It also works for `<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout`.

Answer (score 93):

@Paresh Mayani answer is correct however you can create only tab style

```
<style name="MyCustomTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
  <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

And use it using

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyCustomTextAppearance"
    .../>
```

Comment: @Muhammad Umair Shafique's solution is working. We have to use 'app:tabTextAppearance' atrribute instead of 'style' attribute.

Comment: This seems to be a better answer than the accepted answer, as only 1 style is created.

Answer (score 47):

use this attribute `app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"`
It will work.

```
  <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tablayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabPaddingStart="0dp" />
```

Comment: Only answer here that is pure xml all inside the view element - no need to add external style for this or do anything in Java.  Nice - thanks

Comment: Oh really, because this guy is good at copy&past?! Question is answered with the same solution just one answer above in this thread and that answer gives credit to the owner while this one poses as owner. Here is the answer just above this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/36191045/5636313

Comment: i can't see this answer @Farid

Answer (score 42):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34678235/1025379

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
/>
```

Comment: Confirm, no other answers with more up-votes on this page did the trick for me but this one. My project has minSdkVersion=16, targetSdkVersion=26, Design library version 26.0.0-alpha1 and I'm using the `android.support.design.widget.TabLayout`.

Comment: Not working for `com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout`

Answer (score 17):

In my case two variants work:

1) By Bogdan (susemi99):

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
/>
```

2) By Paresh Mayani. I wanted to have `android:textAllCaps="false"` and `android:textSize="15sp"` simultaneously, so his old method works.

In `styles.xml` write (parent may vary, for instance, "@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget", "TextAppearance.Design.Tab"):

```
<style name="TabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@color/color_blue</item>
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@color/color_blue</item>
    <item name="tabTextColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/TabLayoutTextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="TabLayoutTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
    <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

Apply this style in layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/TabLayout"
    />
```

Answer (score 14):

For those **who can't get working other answers**.

Defining a style is working fine when you have single line tab text.
If you take a close look into the TabLayout, you'll see that it's using a field **design_tab_text_size_2line** when the tabs has more than one line.

The only way I could find to effect this field is to override it in your dimen file.

So put this in your values/dimens.xml

```
<dimen name="design_tab_text_size_2line" tools:override="true">10sp</dimen>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you this is working! Just a little thing I've noticed - when you pass the value as @dimen/10sp a compilation error is showing. You should just pass the sp you need without the "@dimen/" prefix (for example 10sp).

Comment: Thx for the tip :)

Comment: Good find @EvrenOzturk . Thumbs up for you.

Comment: Great find!!!!!

Answer (score 7):

This works for me in just one line

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is simple solution....Enjoy

```
 for (int tabIndex = 0; tabIndex <tabLayout.getTabCount() ; tabIndex++) {
        TextView tabTextView = (TextView)(((LinearLayout)((LinearLayout)tabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(tabIndex)).getChildAt(1));
        tabTextView.setAllCaps(false);
    }
```

Comment: You're making a lot of assumptions about Tab's layout here. Any change of this layout in the library might break your code and it's going to crash. For example, the LinearLayout can change to something else, or the order of children can change.

Answer (score 3):

Try following method and you can implement all the methods of `TextView` in `TabLayout`

```
private void setCustomTab() {

    ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) mTabLayout.getChildAt(0);
    int tabsCount = vg.getChildCount();
    for (int j = 0; j < tabsCount; j++) {
        ViewGroup vgTab = (ViewGroup) vg.getChildAt(j);
        int tabChildsCount = vgTab.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < tabChildsCount; i++) {
            View tabViewChild = vgTab.getChildAt(i);
            if (tabViewChild instanceof TextView) {
                ((TextView) tabViewChild).setTypeface(ResourcesCompat.getFont(this,R.font.montserrat_medium));
                ((TextView) tabViewChild).setAllCaps(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

**Change:** `<item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>`

**With:** `<item name="textAllCaps">false</item>`

Answer (score 3):

This Worked For Me...

```
<style name="TabLayoutStyle" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/TabTextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="TabTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

In versions priror to 14, you need to set (as commented by Paresh Mayani):

```
<style name="MyCustomTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
  <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/MyCustomTextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="MyCustomTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
  <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

But, in case of android version is equal or greater than 14, you need to set:

```
<item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
```

So, if you need to be compatible with versions before and after 14, you **also** need to create a folder values-v14, and a file styles.xml in that folder with the content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <style name="MyCustomTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
      <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 2):

**May 2023** 
Long story short (programmatically)...

Java:

```
/**
 * @param view Target TabLayout view
 * @param caps Present the text caps style
 */
public static void setAllCaps(View view, boolean caps) {
    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++)
            setAllCaps(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i),caps);
    } else if (view instanceof TextView) ((TextView) view).setAllCaps(caps);
}
```

Kotlin :

```
fun setAllCaps(view: View?, caps: Boolean) {
    if (view is ViewGroup) {
        for (i in 0 until view.childCount) setAllCaps(view.getChildAt(i), caps)
    } else if (view is TextView) view.isAllCaps = caps
}
```

Call `setAllCaps` like this :

```
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Recent"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("New"));
    setAllCaps(tabLayout,false);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Here the Simple solution to Avoid Capitalize and change font size , font family on TabLayout design in Android 100% Working**

> Add following style on res/values/stye.xml

```
 <style name="MyCustomTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/poppins_semi_bold</item>
</style>
```

> Call this style in your tab layout as  app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyCustomTextAppearance"

```
      <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_tablayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="#FFF"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyCustomTextAppearance"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/text_app_color"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/text_app_color_1"
        app:tabMode="auto" />
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this in your Java code.  If you are using a SlidingTabLayout look at this sample:

```
protected TextView createDefaultTabView(Context context){
        TextView textView = new TextView(context);
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP);//see line 38 above change the value their in TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP.
        textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);//From DEFAULT_BOLD
        textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#536DFE"));//Text color of the words in the tabs. Indigo A200

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
            // If we're running on Honeycomb or newer, then we can use the Theme's
        // selectableItemBackground to ensure that the View has a pressed state
            TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
            getContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground, outValue, true);
            textView.setBackgroundResource(outValue.resourceId);
        }

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH){
            // If we're running on ICS or newer, enable all-caps to match the Action Bar tab style
            textView.setAllCaps(true);
        }

        int padding = (int)(TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
        textView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);

        return textView;
    }
```

Notice that textView.setAllCaps() has *true* as the perimeter:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH){
            // If we're running on ICS or newer, enable all-caps to match the Action Bar tab style
            textView.setAllCaps(true);
        }
```

When I changed this to (false) it solved the problem for me:

```
textView.setAllCaps(false);
```

Also my string resource file that I use for the tabs looks like this:

```
<string name="tab_title">Title with capital and smaller case</string>
```

However if it had all caps like >TITLE WITH ALL CAPS< you would still of course get all caps in your tabs.

I made no other changes.

It is noteworthy that you can set textView.setAllCaps(false) too, but this made no difference in my case. I just commented out textView.setAllCaps(true).

Answer (score 0):

Changing attributes in XML file doesn't work in Android 11 (SDK 30). Here is code that I use to setup tabs individually using a tab label. It's safer than setting new styles for all text fields in the tabs or relying on the existing tab layout, because the current tab design can be changed by Android. This method assumes that a tab text has been set before the function below is called. Second parameter in the call, txt is a tab label.

```
private fun setTabStyle(tabs: TabLayout, txt: String) {
    val av = ArrayList<View?>()
    tabs.findViewsWithText(av, txt, View.FIND_VIEWS_WITH_CONTENT_DESCRIPTION )
    if (av.count() > 0) {
        val avt = ArrayList<View?>()
        (av[0] as? ViewGroup)?.let {
            for ( i in 0 until it.childCount) {
                val tv = it.getChildAt(i) as? TextView
                tv?.let {t ->
                    if (tv.text == txt) {
                        t.isAllCaps = false
                        t.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 11.toFloat())

                    }
                }

            }

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It'll work if you only add one of these calls.

---

```
        app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"  
        
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
```

---

Answer (score -1):

Just add this to your custom style file

```
<item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
```

I read all the above solutions and all lead to this.