# Android Tablayout Set textAllCaps to False not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I am trying **to make my ViewPager Tab text in small caps but its not working**,

I have searched and checked other post related to this, tried their solution, but still doesn't work

```
<style name="MyCustomTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
      <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/MyCustomTextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="MyCustomTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
      <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

**ViewPager Tab layout**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        app:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/MyCustomTabLayout" />
```

Please any confirmed working solution to this?

thanks.

Comment: have you tried this [http://stackoverflow.com/a/31471430/4217346](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31471430/4217346)

Comment: Any solution to this? I even tried setting tabIndicatorHeight to 25dp in the Theme and it won't update. Seems like the TabLayout won't even respect the assigned Theme.

Comment: No, i ended up using SlidingtabLayout which also has its own issues too.

Answer (score 11):

Its bit late but hope it will help some one.
If you are using support design then you just need to add below mentioned line in your tab layout and get the expected results.

```
app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Try using both
   `<item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
   <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>` in your MyCustomTextAppearance
2. In your ViewPager tab layout, replace `android:theme="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"`with`style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"`

Answer (score 0):

This issue was reported on google https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=202117

where the `app:textAllCaps = "false"` style did not work.

But after release of Android Support Library, revision [23.2.1](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html)  (March 2016) **This issue has been resolved.**

update Support Library to `Android Support Library to 23.2.1`

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this 
The createDefaultTabView() method.

Needed to change textView.setAllCaps(true) to false.

[Sliding tab layout text is uppercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28316454/sliding-tab-layout-text-is-uppercase)