# Android: Setting textAllCaps to false in custom style for TabLayout not working

Tags: android, xml

Note: I don't want to fix this issue by specifying `app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"` in the TabLayout xml, because that overrides the default tab style which I like.

I tried the other solution mentioned here: [Android Tablayout Set textAllCaps to False not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32745413/android-tablayout-set-textallcaps-to-false-not-working), which involved included specifying both `textAllCaps` and `android:textAllCaps` to `false` in my `styles.xml` specification. However, my tab layout continues to show the ta texts as capitalized:

[image]

Below is my **styles.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="standardTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
        <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Below is my **activity_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        style="@style/standardTabLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Calendar" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Input" />
    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify your style in Text Appearance like below :

```
app:tabTextAppearance="@style/standardTabLayout"
```

Tab layout code will look like below :

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    style="@style/standardTabLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/standardTabLayout"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
```