# Android Studio automatically changes button style. Why?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I just developed an app on Android Studio and I used normal default grey button of kitkat. But some time later I made a copy of that app (to make another project) and now in this copied app, new buttons as well as those old buttons are shown with some different style. I am confused as to where I got that new style. It looks cool but I don't want to lose it as automatically as I got it.
I am attaching an image, this will show the changes in design.[image: differences]

Comment: maybe it's for your Android version on device

Comment: You're probably using some other theme.

Comment: Right image shows Material Design buttons, which is standard since Lollipop. Left image is pre-Lollipop, most likely to be KitKat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you are using `Theme.Material` or `Theme.AppCompat`, or something that inherits from those (e.g., `Theme.AppCompat.Light`), as the basis for your app's theme. Or, you have no theme, and you are running on an Android 5.0+ device, and so you get `Theme.Material` by default.

Both `Theme.Material` and `Theme.AppCompat` (the latter in conjunction with `AppCompatActivity` and the rest of the `appcompat-v7` library) aim to implement the Material Design aesthetic, and Material Design says that button captions are in all caps.

Comment: Any easy way to tell the appcompat library to leave my buttons(and buttons only) alone? (some attribute?)

Comment: @Selvin: You can do it in your theme: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26958909/why-is-my-button-text-coerced-to-all-caps-on-lollipop

Comment: Problem is, that in fact it is not a normal Button class but TintButton ... i changed the style but on some device (3.2, yeah i know deprecated but still we use it) it is not working ... so I'm using `MyButton extends Button` in layouts ... also i don't care about CAPS :)

Comment: @Selvin: "that in fact it is not a normal Button class but TintButton" -- yeah, IIRC, that's `appcompat-v7`'s class for handling the `colorAccent` stuff. However, if you apply your own `style` to it, inheriting from something like `Widget.AppCompat.Button`, you should still be able to affect it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes I am using AppCompat copuled with `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'` in gradle. In the previous app, I was compiling `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3`

Answer (score 0):

add this line in style

```
<item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
```