# Is it possible to set android:textAllCaps attribute in PhoneGap Build?

Tags: android, phonegap-build

Is it possible to change the default allcaps setting for Android buttons (android:textAllCaps="false") in PhoneGap Build?

Here it is how is done in native Android apps:
[Why is my Button text forced to ALL CAPS on Lollipop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26958909/why-is-my-button-text-coerced-to-all-caps-on-lollipop)

Comment: I'm sure why someone gave this a plus one, as the question is a complete misunderstanding of how Cordova and Phonegap work.

Answer (score 0):

@besimple,
The question is a complete misunderstanding about how Cordova and Phonegap work. This is [A PHONEGAP FAQ QUESTION](http://phonegap.com/about/faq/).

To answer your question, the visual display (text, buttons, dialogs, etc.) is a subset of HTML. This means you write HTML5 and CSS3 to make your text appear on screen. *You would not* use an `AndroidManifest.xml` directive.

To create your button, you could use a HTML tag like `<div>` or `<button>`. For the style needed to create *allCAPS*, this is done via CSS. This means, if you do NOT know CSS, this is the time to learn. (I believe smallCaps is an option, if not it can be imported)

Two (2) more notes, **1)** you may need to import a complete font set to accomplish this task. **2)** keep all your assets local; the best practice is not to load files from the internet. This include javascript, css, images and font sets.

Best of Luck.

Comment: I see that you completelly misunderstood my question. Maybe I was not clear enough - I am using org.apache.cordova.core.dialogs to display alert message and it uses default theme of the phone for displaying the message. The theme can be changed in native Android apps and even in PhoneGap apps. But my question is - can it be done in PhoneGap Build?

Comment: You question is incorrect. Update your subject line(if you can) and question to reflect what you really want. The answer is *Yes it is possible*.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I am not able to edit the post. So can you help me? What do I have to do to change this setting with PhoneGap  Build? Thanx

Comment: Here is your [HINT](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_config_file_element.md.html#Config%20File%20Elements). Since you want to do it with Android, scroll down to where it says Android. This addtion will modify the final configuration the way you want. If this is not enough, you'll need to write a new SO question. FWIW, it not about giving you the answer. It's that no one will find this answer because the question is wrong - Best of Luck.