# Nativescript - Font style in android. Could not override native Lollipop style(UPPERCASE)

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, nativescript, android-fonts

How I want the button label(font style) to be: Log **i**n, Login **w**ith Facebook, Login **w**ith Twitter.

How I get is: Log **I**n, Login **W**ith Facebook, Login **W**ith Twitter

I have tried the following:

1. Tried the code given in the below link:
   [Why is my Button text forced to ALL CAPS on Lollipop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26958909/why-is-my-button-text-coerced-to-all-caps-on-lollipop)
2. Tried the css (like we use in the HTML5):
   text-transform: none -> No result

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Android Lollipop defaults to capitalized text on buttons. This is the platform default. You can override it using some native methods, see here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatButton.html