# The font style of the button text has changed for the AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, button, fonts

After changing the parent for my activity from `Activity` to `AppCompatActivity`, the font on the buttons changed. For example, `Remove`->`REMOVE`. For other `Vews`, the font has not changed.

Why did the font on the buttons change and how do I get the original font back?

Button:

```
            <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonAddProduct"
            tools:text="Remove"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            style="@style/btns_blue_big" />
```

style:

```
<style name="btns_text_big">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_big</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorMainWhite</item>
</style>

<style name="btns_lo_big" parent="btns_text_big">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">48dp</item>
</style>

<style name="btns_blue_big" parent="btns_lo_big">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_dialog_positive_shape</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The change happens because of Google's Material Design theme.

Basically, when you change your `Activity` to `AppCompatActivity`, you are required to also change your app's theme to extend from `Theme.AppCompat`. This change causes the design for every view to match the theme.

Below are the example between `Holo` theme and `AppCompat` theme:

[image: Holo Theme]

[image: Material / AppCompat Theme]

As you can see, the button's default implementation in `AppCompat` theme uses all caps, so you will need to change those.

A simple fix would be to add these in your styles xml:

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/MyAppTheme.Button</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/MyAppTheme.Button</item>
</style>

<style name="MyAppTheme.Button" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Appcompat Theme, button texts are set to uppercase by default. I have no idea why. 
But if you want to disable it for that button in xml, set `android:textAllCaps="false"`

Programmatically: `button.setTransformationMethod(null);`

Answer (score 1):

*Button text is all-caps by default when using the Material (or DeviceDefault with API 21+) theme. This is working as intended*. If you do not want that you can use below attributes in your style

```
<item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
<item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
```

References is [Why is my Button text forced to ALL CAPS on Lollipop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26958909/why-is-my-button-text-forced-to-all-caps-on-lollipop)