# The text of button at react native is always uppercase

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I created a component at react-native, but the text of the button is always at uppercase, someone knows why it doesn't take the text that pass, because I want to show 'Login', but it shows 'LOGIN'

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Button} from 'react-native';
import LabelApp from "../../config/labels.app";

const labelApp = LabelApp.loginView;

export default class Login extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleClickBtnEnter = this.makeLogin.bind(this);
  }

  makeLogin() {

  }

  render() {
    return (
     <View>
       <Button title= {labelApp.textButtonLogin} onPress={this.handleClickBtnEnter}/>
     </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Label of component

```js
const LabelApp = {
    loginView: {
        textButtonLogin: 'Ingresar',
    },
}
export default LabelApp;
```

[The visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiVzG.png)

Comment: i'm facing the same issue and trying to figure out why react native is not displaying the text as is. why in case of Android the button title is all in uppercase.

Answer (score 9):

For react Native Paper button use uppercase={false} prop:

```
<Button
      mode="outlined"
      uppercase={false}
      accessibilityLabel="label for screen readers"
      style={styles.yourButtonStyle}>Button label</Button>
```

Answer (score 4):

So, the other two answers are correct that you should use TouchableOpacity, but as someone new to React Native, it took me awhile to understand what was going on here. Hopefully this explanation provides a little more context.

The built-in Button component seems to have some weird compatibility/visibility issues on occasion, one of which is rendering the title prop text all uppercase. When viewing the [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/button) for the Button component in Chrome, the preview shows all text being capitalized under the "Web" view but not Android or iOS (I was having this issue using Expo and Metro Bundler on an Android device, so not sure what to make of this). I couldn't find anything about capitalization/uppercase in the Button docs, so perhaps this is a bug.

**The solution is to use a different component called [TouchableOpacity](https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchableopacity).** It also has an onPress event you can use and a built-in touch animation, but it has less out of the box styling than the Button component. Important to note from docs: "Opacity is controlled by wrapping the children in an Animated.View, which is added to the view hierarchy. Be aware that this can affect layout." It doesn't have a title prop, so you just put the button text in a Text component, like so:

```
<Button 
  title='text will be capitalized' 
  onPress={onPress}
/>
```

becomes

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
  <Text>text will stay lowercase</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

I was having the same issue as OP, and this solved it for me.

Answer (score 3):

From the official [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/button)

> A basic button component that should render nicely on any platform. ***Supports a minimal level of customization.***

The recommend use of touchable opacity or touchable native feedback

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity

Below I've added `textTransform: 'lowercase',` as a style rule for the button to override any inherited text casing.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native'

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { count: 0 }
  }

  onPress = () => {
    this.setState({
      count: this.state.count+1
    })
  }

 render() {
   return (
     <View style={styles.container}>
       <TouchableOpacity
         style={styles.button}
         onPress={this.onPress}
       >
         <Text> Touch Here </Text>
       </TouchableOpacity>
       <View style={[styles.countContainer]}>
         <Text style={[styles.countText]}>
            { this.state.count !== 0 ? this.state.count: null}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingHorizontal: 10
  },
  button: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#DDDDDD',
    padding: 10,
    textTransform: 'lowercase', // Notice this updates the default style
  },
  countContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 10
  },
  countText: {
    color: '#FF00FF'
  }
})
```

https://snack.expo.io/Bko_W_gx8

Comment: Thanks, i am going to use TouchableOpacity

Answer (score 2):

This question is 3 years old and I'm not sure why no one has answered it correctly until now.

Native android buttons are all caps by default starting from android lollipop, which is what react native uses when you use the control `Button from react-native` in your app. To override the functionality, you just need to add this line in your styles.xml file inside your app theme (not the splash screen style)

```
<item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
```

You can get more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30464346/11104068

The changes are not going to apply instantly obviously since the change is in the native xml file and not in a JavaScript file. So you will need to do a `npm/yarn run android`.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code and it looks like it's the expected behaviour with `Button` component from `react-native`

You can see this at the [official documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/button)

I believe that you need to change `Button` component, take it from another package to meet your needs.

As an alternative you can create your own button

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Button, TouchableHighlight, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import LabelApp from "../../config/labels.app";

const labelApp = LabelApp.loginView;

export default class Login extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleClickBtnEnter = this.makeLogin.bind(this);
  }

  makeLogin() {

  }

  render() {
    return (
     <View>
       <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.handleClickBtnEnter} underlayColor="white">
         <View style={styles.button}>
           <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{labelApp.textButtonLogin}</Text>
         </View>
       </TouchableHighlight>
     </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    marginBottom: 30,
    width: 260,
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#2196F3'
  },
  buttonText: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    padding: 20,
    color: 'white'
  }
});
```

Comment: are you sure?, it is not possible to change the text when i use button

Comment: I've edited my answer to provide you a workaround, tell me if it works for you

Comment: Thanks, i understood why i need to change the element. it was useful

Answer (score -1):

```js
            <Button
                style={{
                  borderRadius: 10,
                  backgroundColor: "#000",
                  width: 200,
                  height: 50,
                }}
              >
                <Text
                 uppercase={false} 
                >
                  Login
                </Text>
              </Button>
```

Comment: You described it right , but gave wrong code sample , textTransform :'none' , on all buttons shout remove all capitalise styles .